# PHP include problem

Tags: php, apache, file, filesystems, include

Index.php -> includes init.php
init.php -> includes config.php
config.php -> contains the configuration

Not the problem is that I am able to access content from config.php into index.php but when I trying to access data from init.php or index.php into config.php it is not happening.

If i put echo "i am text" in config.php and run index.php then nothing is displayed on the screen but when i run "echo $item_from_config_file" then it does output data as set in config.php

Please help and suggest a way of getting around this problem as it is driving me mad.

Comment: use require() and turn on error-reporting in php.ini.

Comment: Can we see your code + the paths that are in it?

Comment: still the same results with require()

Comment: include.php => //Include the initialisation file
require "init.php"; init.php => //Include the configuration file
require "lib/config.php"; cofig.php =>
define("SITE_URL", "http://example.com/");

Comment: @user381695, Please use the FAQ If your unsure how to edit your post, and what the best practises are, We cant help you without some code to look at! - Were programmers not magicians

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the order isn't okay. Make sure you include all the files first then try to access their variables.

config.php:

```
$variable = "foo";
```

init.php:

```
include("config.php");
$variable.= " bar";
```

index.php:

```
include("init.php");
echo $variable;
```

Comment: Guys I apologize, I realised that the code was right. The latest file was not uploading. oops. sorry. I am gonna upvote all your answers so you all get a credit. Please write an answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the config.php file doesn't know anything about the init.php file, it's just being put inside it.

So, there's no way for config.php to directly read from init.php if it's being included.

I'd suggest integrating config.php into init.php.

Comment: but it does work when i execute something from init.php which is only set in index.php although init.php is also just put into the index.php